# Most efficient way to filter files by content

Tags: c#, .net, list, file, filter

I am using the .NET framework and I would like to develop a tool that would be able to filter files out depending of their content.

A little bit of context
I have numerous files representing deck lists (mtg).
They all look very similar, and follow this pattern: {number} {card name} \n

Ex:

```
2 Watery Grave
1 Polluted Delta
1 Steam Vents
```

*Note: for what I want to achieve the number is irrelevant and can be ignored.*

The goal is to find 3 decks with with no matching cards.

To do so we I need to update a list of 'remaining available decks' which is filtered depending of the decks already selected.

Ex:

When no deck is selected yet, the 'remaining available decks' list contains all of the files.

Then let's say the deck used as an exemple above is selected, the list will update to only contain the files that do NOT contain Watery Grave, Polluted Delta or Steam Vents.

Because of the quantity of files involved, I am scared of the performances of doing this search by opening and reading each file once a deck is selected.

If someone has some input regarding how to efficiently implement this, like a third-party framework, a specific design pattern, or a custom class that would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How many files are you thinking you might have?  You say you are nervous about opening each file to scan the contents, is there some master list that will tell you what file has what deck? If not, I don't see what other choice you have, unless at startup you read all the files and then store the data somehow so that you are only reading the file data once per application run, but if you don't have a master list, I don't see what other option remains other than to read everything.

Comment: you are right, the only way to do it is look at each file, and try to efficiently search the contents. however you should think about solving the problem at the source by keeping a db of the files or a least a manifest of what files might need to be identified at time of creation. this will save you having to look at each file

Comment: About a 1000 files, each having about 35 lines.